# How to validate a prediction in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, classification

I am going through the [Kaggle Digit Recognizer Tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer/overview/tutorial) and I'm trying to understand how all of this works. I would like to validate a **predicted** value. Basically, I have a prediction that's wrong, but I want to see what the actual value of that prediction was. I think I am way off:

`...`

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/train.csv')

labels = df['label'].values
x_train = df.drop(columns=['label']).values / 255
# trying to produce a crappy dataset for train/test
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_train, labels, test_size=0.95)


# Purposely trying to get a crappy model so I can learn about validation
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
# model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
# model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
predictions = model.predict([x_test])


index_to_predict = 0
print('Prediction: ', np.argmax(predictions[index_to_predict]))
print('Actual:     ', predictions.argmax(axis=-1)[index_to_predict])
print(predictions.shape)
vals = x_test[index_to_predict].reshape(28, 28)
plt.imshow(vals)
```

This yields the following:

[image]

How can I get a true 'heres the prediction' and 'heres the actual' breakdown? My logic on getting the actual is definitely off.

Comment: how about confusion matrix ?

Comment: Well, I'm already personally in that matrix right now.

Comment: that should help you understand the training better. Also you can write the target and predicted values along with image name in a csv file , and inspect them with some filters in excel or some spreadsheet will give a better perspective usually for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The true labels (also sometimes called target values, or ground-truth labels) are stored in `y_train` and `y_test` for training and test set respectively. Therefore, you can easily just print that to find the true label:

```
print('Actual:', y_test[index_to_predict])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
y_test[index_to_predict]
```

will have the actual label and

```
predictions[index_to_predict]
```

should have the predicted probability values for each of your classes.